# Python list append based on substring search - slow performance

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

In a list of lists, I need to add a list element to each inner list, whenever one or more elements of another list are contained in a fixed position element of the inner list itself.

Here's an example of the lists

```
list1 = ['AS23X2', '33YK87', 'YY744Q']
list2 = [[0, 1773332, 'some text that may contain 0, 1 or more occurrences of list1 items'], [1, 77666543, 'some other text 33YK87 is here']]
```

Note that `len(list1)` is about 95,000 and `len(list1)` over 120,000. The requirement is that if more than 1 item of `list1` is found within `list2[n][2]`, they are all appended as a list.

The below code does exactly what is required, but is very slow (takes several minutes). I can't figure out how to improve performance - can anyone suggest a possible solution?

```
    for i in list2:
        i.append([x for x in list1 if x in i[2]])
```

Please do consider that `list2` is derived from a Pandas dataframe:

```
list2 = df2.values.to_list()
```

I'm quite confident there's something more efficient that could be achieved using Pandas, but I'm new to it and hope someone already solved a similar question in a better way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm just spit balling ideas:

- Use a database
- Use multithreading library
- Try to do something with Set if the dataset includes many duplicates
- Or try using Counter from the collections library to remove duplicates, but keep occurrences. I'm not sure if this will be faster given your dataset

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried with Sql Server - where data actually resides, but that is much slower, since the string column where the search needs to be done is too long for indexing. Also, there are no duplicates to be removed